# Verifying the proof of this Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, fake-proofs

I want to **verify the proof of this Lemma**:

**Lemma**: If a real analytic function $g$ has infinitely many real zeros, then there exist no $w∈ℝ$ such that the fiber $g⁻¹(w)$ is finite.

**Proof**: Since the zeros of $g$ are isolated, then there exist a bijection between the zero set $Z(g)$ of $g$ and $ℤ$. Thus, we can identify $Z(g)$ by integers. For every $n$, let $I_{n}=(n,n+1)$. If $w>0$ and $g>0$ on some $I_{n}$, then $g>0$ on each interval $I_{n+2k}$ and the supremum of $g$ on $I_{n+2k}$ goes to infinity when $k→∞$. Assume that this maximum is at least $w$ for every $k≥k_{w}$ and let $k≥k_{w}$. Then, $g(n+2k)=0$ and $g(n+2k+w_{k})≥w$ for some $0≤w_{k}≤1$. By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $s_{k}$ in the interval $(n+2k,n+2k+w_{k}]$ such that $g(s_{k})=a$. Hence ${s_{k}:k≥k_{a}}⊂g⁻¹(a)$, which is infinite. The same method for $w<0$.

Comment: What is the question? The proof is of course wrong '$\cos$ there are counterexamples.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I want to see the wrong step in the proof and how to fix it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ok and thank you for clarification. Can we add some assumptions to the function $f$ in order to get the Lemma correct.

Comment: Yes, if we demand that the function assumes arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values (for all $K > 0$, there are $a,b$ with $g(a) < -K$ and $g(b) > K$), the assertion becomes correct. The argument is similar to the one here, but you can't assume that the sign alternates between pairs of successive zeros (you could force that by demanding that all zeros have odd multiplicity, but that would be unnecessarily restrictive), and you can't assume that between two intervals where $\lvert g\rvert$ gets large, there are no intervals where it remains small (so no $k_w$).

Comment: @DanielFischer: I try to follow the arguments when the function assumes arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values. However I am not able to give a proof. Can you tel me about the steps in some details.

Comment: Suppose $g(x) = w$ had only finitely many solutions. That means there are $a < b$ such that $g(x) \neq w$ for $w < a$ or $w > b$. Let $c$ be the largest zero of $g$ smaller than $a$, and $d$ the smallest zero larger than $b$. Let $K = \max \{\lvert g(x)\rvert:c\leqslant x\leqslant d\}+\lvert w\rvert$. By assumption, there are $u,v$ with $g(u) < -K$ and $g(v) > K$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is an $x_w$ between $c$ or $d$ and $u$ or $v$ with $g(x_w) = w$. Contradiction.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Good answer. Thank you very much. I remark that you have a very big degree of intelegence, then how you cannot solve some of the famous problems such as Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Who knows, maybe I have solved it but didn't tell anybody? Seriously, though, the famous unsolved problems are unsolved and famous because they're _really hard_.

Comment: Attacking interesting problems even if they're very hard is a good thing. Just a) be aware that you probably will not solve something like the Riemann Hypothesis, but b) you'll be in great company if you don't (Hardy, Ramanujan, ...). If you keep these two things in mind, wrestling with the problem is still fun, and you learn a lot from it. And if chance decides you're the one to crack it, cool.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Why must there be zeroes outside the closed interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: It's part of the premises that $g$ has infinitely many zeros. Also, $g$ is analytic, so $g$ has only finitely many zeros in the compact interval $[a,b]$ (or $g$ is identically $0$, but that has been ruled out by the premise that it take arbitrarily large values), hence there must be infinitely many outside the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to see the wrong step in the proof.

Okay.

> **Proof:** Since the zeros of $g$ are isolated, then there exist a bijection between the zero set $Z(g)$ of $g$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, we can identify $Z(g)$ by integers.

Correct so far.

> For every $n$, let $I_n=(n,n+1)$.

That's a bit fishy, but I guess we can let that pass as "abuse of notation".

> If $w>0$ and $g>0$ on some $I_n$, then $g>0$ on each interval $I_{n+2k}$

$x \mapsto x^2\cdot \cos x$ begs to differ.

> and the supremum of $g$ on $I_{n+2k}$ goes to infinity when $k\to\infty$.

Why should it? $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

> Assume that this maximum is at least $w$ for every $k\geqslant k_w$ and let $k \geqslant k_w$. Then, $g(n+2k)=0$ and $g(n+2k+w_k)\geqslant w$ for some $0\leqslant w_k\leqslant 1$. By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $s_k$ in the interval $(n+2k,n+2k+w_k]$

**If** the preceding parts *were* okay, that would be too, if we accept the abuse of notation.

> such that $g(s_k)=a$.

What is $a$, suddenly?

> Hence $s_k : k \geqslant k_a\subset g^{-1}(a)$, which is infinite.

Are there set braces missing? $\{s_k : k \geqslant k_a \} \subset g^{-1}(a)$? That would make at least notational sense.

> The same method for $w<0$.

Well, ...

> and how to fix it.

I don't see that it could be fixed, since the assertion is false. There are real-analytic functions $g$ with infinitely many zeros such that $g^{-1}(w)$ is finite for some $w$.